# Do you think this is a good Magento setup?

Tags: performance, magento, database-replication

Rackspace Cloud Hosting

```
**Domain.com**
DynDNS
Private Whois
Full DynDNS Name servers and DNS
Remove www to domain.com

**Server Magento 1**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
APC
Memcache

**Server Magento 2**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
APC
Memcache

Server Magento 1 and Server Magento 2 (Load Balanced + will be in replication)

**DB Server 1**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
Memcache
MySQL 5

**DB Server 2**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
Memcache
MySQL 5

DB Magento 1 and DB Magento 2 (Load Balanced + will be in replication)

**CDN Server**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
APC
Memcache

CDN server will be in sync using C Names to MaxNDA, Cloud files or S3
```

Comment: There is no APC on Server Magento 1, is it normal?

Comment: Why do you have nginx, php and APC on the database server?

Comment: I thought memcache is a module and helps installing it on the server, I edited the APC - yes all servers have it. Nginx on DB as I like it and though it performs better - I want to be able to access phpMyAdmin on all DB servers so need PHP - APC would be better because I can cache my PHPMyADMIN sessions??

Comment: You can use 1 phpMyAdmin that access on remote database. You need only 1 phpMyAdmin. Also you should keep database server only for database.

Comment: In Magento you are using memcache for caching (normally for distributed caching when you have load balancing). In the case you are using distributed caching you need only one memcache on 1 of the 2 magento server.

Comment: It's totaly related with your product quantity. We have 2500 products and 100 mbit direct connection, 4 GB / RHEL ( database and magento work on the same server ) which is working slow performance in sometimes.

Comment: I am not sure that the quantity of product have much impact on the performance of Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you:

```
**Server Magento 1**
1024 MB DDR (may be to low)
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
APC: only for opcode
cache: file because you don't have enough memory to use APC

**Server Magento 2**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
APC: only for opcode
cache: file because you don't have enough memory to use APC

Server Magento 1 and Server Magento 2 (Load Balanced + will be in replication)

**DB Server 1**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD

**DB Server 2** 
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD

DB and DB2 (DB2 is just a copy of DB1 used for backup)
(some people use one db for writing and the other for reading)

**CDN Server**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
```

other possibilities with distributed caching:

```
**Server Magento 1**
1024 MB DDR (may be to low)
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
APC: only for opcode
cache: fast backend memcache db2 and slow backend database

**Server Magento 2**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
Nginx
PHP-FPM
APC: only for opcode
cache: fast backend memcache db2 and slow backend database

Server Magento 1 and Server Magento 2 (Load Balanced + will be in replication)

**DB Server 1**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD

**DB Server 2** 
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
memcache

**CDN Server**
1024 MB DDR
40 GB HD
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 1Go of Ram for Magento server it's a bit short. Also depends which kind of cache do you use but look like you will used cache in memory?
Which system of cache do you plan to use? Because you are doing load balancing... Do you plan to distribute the between the 2 servers or to have a system of cache on each server?

Your configuration sound a bit strange :s